# Extract only the keys and its repeated value from dict and put in another one

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict that represents the "serial number" of a product as a key and the product as a value. something like that: product = {12345678:"Television",23456789:"Stereo Sound",34567890:"Television"}
my dict has a lot of products, and I want to create a dict for each key,value pair, with repeated "Televisions" keys for exemple in the same dict. Is there some way I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
product = {12345678:"Television",23456789:"Stereo Sound",34567890:"Television"}

new_dict = {}
items = [v for k, v in product.items()]

for i in items:
    new_dict[i] = [k for k, v in product.items() if v == i]
new_dict
# {'Television': [12345678, 34567890], 'Stereo Sound': [23456789]}
```